# Pass Pointer to First Packet Between Methods (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, pointers, coremidi

I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The first version of this works:

```
- (void) sendBytes:(const UInt8*)bytes size:(UInt32)size
{
    Byte packetBuffer[size+100];
    MIDIPacketList *packetList = (MIDIPacketList*)packetBuffer;
    MIDIPacket     *packet     = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
    MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, sizeof(packetBuffer), packet, 0, size, bytes);
    [self sendPacketList:packetList];
}
```

For DRYness, I try to make a method out of the packet list creation:

```
- (MIDIPacketList*) makePacketList:(const UInt8*)data size:(UInt32)size
{
    Byte packetBuffer[size+100];
    MIDIPacketList *packetList = (MIDIPacketList*)packetBuffer;
    MIDIPacket     *packet     = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
    MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, sizeof(packetBuffer), packet, 0, size, data);
    return packetList;
}


- (void) sendBytes:(const UInt8*)bytes size:(UInt32)size
{
    MIDIPacketList *packetList = [self makePacketList:bytes size:size];
    [self sendPacketList:packetList];
}
```

And now the `sendPacketList` method fails with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Using GDB, the `packetList` still looks good even within `sendPacketList`...

[Looking at the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMidi/Reference/MIDIServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html), it seems that the thing I'm passing around is just a pointer to the first packet in the list. So... how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that `Byte packetBuffer[size+100]` declares a local array, which must not be accessed after that method exits. You have two options (which I'll write as functions):

### Option 1:

```
MIDIPacketList *makePacketList(const UInt8 *data, UInt32 size) {
    Byte *packetBuffer = malloc(size + 100);
    MIDIPacketList *packetList = (MIDIPacketList*)packetBuffer;
    MIDIPacket     *packet     = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
    MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, sizeof(packetBuffer), packet, 0, size, data);
    return packetList;
}
```

If you do it this way, you'll have to `free()` the buffer later on, which is kind of a pain.

### Option 2:

```
MIDIPacketList *makePacketList(Byte *packetBuffer, const UInt8 *data, UInt32 size) {
    MIDIPacketList *packetList = (MIDIPacketList*)packetBuffer;
    MIDIPacket     *packet     = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
    MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, size + 100, packet, 0, size, data);
    return packetList;
}
```

In this case, you'll have to declare the `Byte packetBuffer[size + 100]` outside of the function and pass it in as the first argument, which is also somewhat inconvenient.

Comment: Thanks for answering (as always). In Option 1, where would I free the buffer, and if it's outside the method, how would I get a handle to it? In option two, I can just let it go out of scope like in the calling method, right?

Comment: @Yar: The buffer is what's returned by the method. It's actually a bit redundant to have both `packetBuffer` and `packetList`, since they're actually the same value. But I figured you might find it more clear to have both, so I kept it.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. `void makePacketList(MIDIPacketList *packetList, const UInt8 *data, UInt32 size)` does work, but in practice it's actually more concise to use the function to cast, as well. Seems clunky but it's the best possible alternative.