# Call Static Method with C Syntax in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I could redo this method using proper Obj-C syntax, but I was wondering how to call this from Obj-C. The method looks like this

```
@interface YarMidiCommon : NSObject

static
MIDIPacketList *makePacketList(Byte *packetBuffer, const UInt8 *data, UInt32 size);

@end
```

but I have no idea how to call that method.  I have tried

```
Byte packetBuffer[size+100];
MIDIPacketList *packetList = makePacketList(packetBuffer, bytes, size);
```

but the error is "has internal linkage but is not defined." Is this possible without resorting to "proper" Obj-C syntax?

For the record, the method that I want to emulate would be something like

```
+ (MIDIPacketList*) makePacketListWithPacketBuffer:(Byte*)packetBuffer data:(const UInt8 *)data size:(UInt32)size;
```

which is verbose and annoying, seeing as everything here is C anyway.

[This is related to this other answer I got today.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750257/8047)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the function is a C function you need to remove the static keyword or else it will not be visible outside of its translation unit. Once you do that the first example you have will work. Also since it is a C function placing its declaration inside or outside of the `@interface` and definition inside or outside of the `@implementation` makes no difference on how you will call it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the declaration as being equivalent to static C function in the global scope. This is much unlike C++ or Java. There is no class scope or external linkage for this function.

As such, the @interface scope would not be a good place to declare `makePacketList`. The message means the definition is not visible when you use it.

Comment: Does that mean "don't do it?"

Comment: @Yar That means remove the static keyword. Also see my answer for the importance of placing the method declaration inside of `@interface`. hint: it is none.

Comment: @Yar yes. there's currently no reason to declare a function (static or extern) in an `@interface`. it's just a C function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the function to the `.m` (makes sense if you use it from this file only) or remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: If I remove the static keyword, do I need to instantiate YarMidiCommon?

Comment: No, it is a plain C function not being the part of an obj-c class.